# Load more json objects in scroll down

Tags: angular

the overall jsons objects is 100

first show the 20  objects

after scroll to show next 20 objects

after its continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the DataScroller of primeng : https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datascroller